# What is explicit map?

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is an explicit map?
In my text it was said that, constructing an explicit map between two groups preserving the group operations or providing no such map exists is, except in tiny cases, computationally unfeasible.
So what does this mean

Comment: An explicit map between groups $G$ and $G'$ most likely means you list all the elements of $G$, and you list all the elements of $G'$, and for each element of $G$, you write down exactly what element of $G'$ it maps to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Explicit" in this case probably means some kind of formula giving the isomorphism.

Here's an analogy: every real polynomial of degree $7$ has at least one real root, but there won't be an "explicit formula" telling you the root except in some easy cases.

In abstract algebra it may be possible to show that two groups are isomorphic with an indirect argument that doesn't explicitly find an isomorphism.